# Why PhpStorm Built-in Server can understand URL rewrite rule but the others webserver can't

Tags: php, nginx, webserver, phpstorm

I convert the structure of old project into an MVC. New structure similar to Laravel with `Router`. An example:

```php
$router->add('admin/{controller}/{action}', ['namespace' => 'Admin']);
```

When deploying project by PhpStorm - PHP Built-in server, it works well. I know that it requires to config `.htaccess` or `nginx` to make webserver understand.

Is there any other ways except config server like PhpStorm PHP Built-in server? I tried to find how PhpStorm handle it but it seems no documentations.

The new structure that I use: https://github.com/daveh/php-mvc

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not relevant, but I would recommend Laravel if you are restructuring an old project.

Comment: Thank you but it is just small internal project, so team leader want to it smaller, simple as possible.

Comment: [PhpStorm's built-in web server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php-built-in-web-server.html) uses actual [PHP's built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) .. that supports a special [router script](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php#example-483) for non-existing resources, otherwise it just sends them to the default **index file**.

Comment: @LazyOne thank you so much! This is exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

PHPStorm is obviously doing some extra work.

Redirect from the URL requires some kind of code to do. As you have noted it requires a .htaccess file or ngnix config.

PHPStorm is either reading these files or because it is a dev server it is guessing at what you want to do.

Comment: I don't know how PHPStorm can understand that without htaccess and nginx configurations. Please let me know if you know any ways to do that.

Comment: just redirects everything to index.php like the .htaccess file does

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. Does it mean when i access url like `admin/login/`, I have to create an folder login/index.php and inside login/index.php I redirect to main index.php?